# Traducir consulta a Eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

He tratado de traducir esta consulta a eloquen pero hasta ahora no lo logro, alguien sabe como puedo hacerlo?

```
update usuarios set asignacion='gestion' where id='8';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que tienes un modelo Usuario declarado en tu proyecto, puede quedar de la siguiente manera

**CON AYUDA DE ELOQUENT**

```
$actualiza = Usuario::where('id', 8)
             ->update(['asignacion' => 'gestion']);
```

Primero usamos el `where` para encontrar el registro con id 8 en la tabla `usuarios` y posteriormente a través del método `update` pasamos un arreglo asociativo, donde la clave es el nombre de la columna y el valor es el nuevo valor asignado a esa columna en ese id específico

Si te decides por este método y tienes en tu tabla las columnas `updated_at`; entonces en tu modelo deberás declarar lo siguiente

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

Para que de este modo dicha columna no intente ser objeto de la actualización, así solo se actualizarán los datos de las columnas que tu indiques

**CON AYUDA DEL QUERY BUILDER FLUENT**

```
$actualiza = \DB::table('usuarios')
                ->where('id', 8)
                ->update(['asignacion' => 'gestion']);
```

Hacemos uso del facade \DB para invocar por su nombre a la tabla por medio del método `table` y después el procedimiento restante es el mismo al usado en Eloquent